# what is a MIA satellite

Tags: satellite

I came across this sentence in a magazine:

> We sit outside the Lorne Community Hall, Victoria, watching the MIA satellite overhead.

I wonder if the author is talking about an artificial satellite. Can one recognize an artificial satellite with naked eyes?

Thanks for response.

Comment: Could you add a citation so we can check out the article?

Comment: All other parts of the article have to do with the main topic- the boots that accompanied the author in his travel to many places.

Comment: Context can be everything. Was he in Australia?

Comment: Lorne, Victoria is in Australia

Comment: @Omen Just what I thought.

Comment: This question probably would be best on Space Exploration.SE

Comment: i would guess "missing in action" (like in the military), but if you are seeing it overhead, that doesnt make sense

Answer (score 2):

As @usethedeathstar said, MIA satellite most likely means ['Missing In Action'](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Missing_in_action). The following lyrics from the song 'MIA satellite' seems to solidify this:

> MIA Satellite-
>   You've got no path in sight.
>   You leave me hanging in the dead of night-
>   In the dead of night.

Regarding the ability to identify artificial satellites, it is possible to identify some satellites. Some identification guides:

#### Iridium

Iridium satellites are usually faster than most satellites, but their tell-tale sign is that they go from dim to bright to dim as they rotate. This bright flash is known as an Iridium Flare.

#### ISS

This moves East to West and is brighter than the average satellite.

Comment: Do you have any evidence to back this up?

Comment: @HDE226868 The MIA satellite bit or the identification?

Comment: The MIA satellite bit. I thought you were fine with the identification.